# Seaborn renders plots slowly in apache zeppelin notebooks

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, apache-zeppelin

I am currently trying to generate visualizations in zeppelin (0.8.1) notebooks using the pyspark interpreter with python 3.7.3.

Generating the following simple plot with seaborn (0.9.0) takes around 5 minutes (with very high CPU usage throughout the duration):

```
%pyspark
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,3))

sns.pairplot(data)
```

This behavior is rather inconsistent as the following (much more data intensive) plot is rendered instantly

```
%pyspark
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.rand(10000,2))

sns.lineplot(x = 0, y = 1, data = df)
```

I noticed that using matplotlib (3.1.0) is generally much faster for and almost as snappy as I am used to from jupyter notebook environments.

I have already read about issue [ZEPPELIN-1894](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1894) but I can render the mentioned scatterplot instantly as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after posting [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-4358?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=16940290#comment-16940290) the solution is to use the `%spark.ipyspark` interpreter, this might require installing additional packages:

```
pip install protobuf grpcio
```